# pythonのmatplotlibにてget_yticklabels関数でy軸のtickラベルの情報が取得できない

Tags: python, matplotlib

実現したいこと。
画像のようにY軸のtickラベルの数字を書き換えたいです。

具体的には、plotしたY軸のtickラベルの数字に対して、「¥」マークを付けて
tickラベルを更新したいです。

考え方として、「get_yticklabels」を使って「Y軸のtickラベル」のデータの取得し、set_textで更新を試みたのですが、get_yticklabelsで空文字しか取得できません。

もし解決方法を知っている方がいましたら教えてください。

**現状のソースコード**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5] , [3,4,5,6,7])

fig.show()
y_labels = ax1.get_yticklabels()

#get_yticklabelsでY軸の数値を取りたいがなぜか取れない(空白になる)

for i  in  range(len(y_labels)):
    lable = y_labels[i]
    text = lable.get_text()
    text = '¥' + text
    lable.set_text(text)


#ax1.set_yticklabels(y_labels) #このまま左記を実行すると　ｙ軸のラベルに「¥」のみ表示されてしまう
plt.show()
```

**出力結果**

[image: 実現したいこと]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この記事の応用で出来るようになります。
[Modify tick label text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11244514/9014308)

`#`でコメント付けたところが変更点です。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5] , [3,4,5,6,7])

fig.canvas.draw()  # fig.show()ではなくこちらを使う
y_labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax1.get_yticklabels()]  # リスト内包表記でラベル配列取得

for i  in  range(len(y_labels)):
    y_labels[i] = '¥' + y_labels[i]  # 単純に文字列前に挿入

ax1.set_yticklabels(y_labels)  # 変更したラベルを設定
plt.show()
```

表示結果
[image: result_Figure1]

Comment: ありがとうございます！早速試したところ、想定通りの動きになりました。また、参考記事もありがとうございます。参考になります！